# Difficulty hiding image with no src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of the following elements:

```
<div class="slidetpl">
  <img src >
</div>
```

I want to hide .slidetpl if the image has no source. To do that I have tried the following:

```
$('.slidetpl img').each(function () {
        if (this.src.length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
   });
```

But this is not working.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: In case you got an answer to your problem, don't hesitate to check one of the following answers as the one that solved your issue ;) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slidetpl img[src=""]').parent().hide();
    $('.slidetpl img:not([src=""])').parent().show(); //Can be removed.
});
```

Comment: op wants to hide the image's parent, not the image itself

Comment: Thanks! I made a slight adjustment and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

This does the effect for me:

```js
// Start an immediate invocable function expression, to auto 
// execute the internal code and isolate the code from the 
// outside JS scope.
(function( $, window, undefined ){

  // Find all the document images and iterate over them. In case you like to
  // to iterate only under slidetpl change the selector from
  // img to .slidetpl img
  $( 'img' ).each(
    function() {

      // If the empty string is equal with the src attribute of 
      // of the current item in the iteration
      if ( '' === $(this).attr('src') ) {

        // Then hide the current item in the iteration.
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
  );
})( jQuery, this )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" />
<img src />
<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/icon-sets/web-2-orange-2/running-man-xxl.png" />
```

Note, the above code will hide all the images with empty `src` attribute. In case you like to hide only the children elements of the `.slidetpl` then you can modify the selector from `img` to `.slidetpl img`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slidetpl img[src=""]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, just missing the correct syntax of `this`, refer below:

```
if ($(this).attr('src').length == 0)
```

Watch out the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/5rktkk3a/).